# New to Arch Linux, can't log into my wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux

I have a general problem with Arch Linux. Every time I reboot or shut my computer down and start it up again Arch Linux seems not to remember any setting I tried to set up previously. Because of that I never have Wifi and the commands I used to set up wifi I forgot and cant find again. 
Because of that I can't run any pacman command.

So my questions:
How can I make my computer to remember settings?
How can I set up my wifi?

PS: Running 'ip link' shows my wifi-card, so the system seems to find it.

Comment: You're not running a live arch ISO, all in ram, are you? Do other settings get saved, like new files in your home are still there after a reboot?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the Info, my problem ist, that when I create a file (for example `touch test.txt`) then when rebooting this file stays there. So it does not get deleted.

Comment: @HelmutK. May I ask if there is any DE (Desktop Environment) installed?

Comment: @funilrys Thanks for asking, I decided that I am not yet there with arch linux I installed Debian on my Computer and will explore the wondersome world of Linux with Debian and i3 as a WM on Debian.